# iOS SEアプリが起動しません

Tags: バグ, サポート

Stack ExchangeのアプリがiOSデバイスで起動しません。“Request failed. Tap to retry” と表示される状態で数時間経過しました。どうすればよいですか。

Answer (score 3):

MSEに詳しく書かれていました。以下は[Brian Nickel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/324693/314875)さんの回答の日本語訳です。

---

一度ログアウトして再度ログインする必要があります。

> モバイルAPIが安全ではないと思わせる原因となったリファクタリングの後、さまざまな自動アクションによってアクセストークンが無効になりました。
>
> 変更は元に戻され、修正が識別されました。Visual Studioの "Find Usaged" 機能が `#if !DEBUG`ブロック内のコードを見逃していたのが原因だったようです。